# IOS, How Can I Create A Center Tabbed Scrollable TableView Like This

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I need to create a tabbed view like this, for the first I need to make header to hide on scrolling and then I need to swipe between tabs on the center.
Can anyone suggest me which component should I use here?
[The Attached Image, Please Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQArn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip
This control can help, although, you'll have to hide the header on your own
Refer this too, https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout